# Can I use the system variable names in the msbuild settings?

Tags: msbuild

Can I use the system variable names in the msbuild settings? I want to write something like that:

```
<Import Project="%ProgramData%\MyCompany\config\AutoCAD\acad-common.props" />
```

instead of that:

```
<Import Project="C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\config\AutoCAD\acad-common.props" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are available for msbuild as normal properties so can be used with the standard `$(Property)` syntax like

```
<Import Project="$(ProgramData)\MyCompany\config\AutoCAD\acad-common.props" />
```